# Remembering the Portmanteau Theorem

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking for a good way to remember/understand part of the [Portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures). Specifically, let $X$ be a metric space. The part of the Portmanteau theorem I'm asking about says that for a sequence $\mu_n$ of Borel probability measures on $X$ and another such measure $\mu$, the following are equivalent:

1. $\int f\, d\mu_{n} \to \int f\, d\mu$ for every bounded, continuous, real-valued $f$;
2. $\limsup \mu_n(C) \leq \mu(C)$ for every closed $C \subset X$;
3. $\liminf \mu_n(U) \geq \mu(U)$ for every open $U \subset X$.

I have trouble remembering if the $\limsup$ goes with the closed or open sets and which way the inequalities go.

Is there an easy way to see why, for example, 1. isn't equivalent to $\liminf \mu_n(U) \leq \mu(U)$ for every open $U\subset X$?

Answer (score 2):

Of the two possibilities for $\le$:
$$
\limsup_n \mu_n(A)\le \mu(A)\qquad\text{vs.}\qquad\liminf_n\mu_n(A)\le\mu(A)
$$
remember that Portmanteau has the **stronger** condition, since $\liminf\le\limsup$. Similarly for $\ge$ Portmanteau has the stronger condition of the two possibilities:
$$\limsup_n \mu_n(A)\ge \mu(A)\qquad\text{vs.}\qquad\liminf_n\mu_n(A)\ge\mu(A)
$$
As for whether these apply to open $A$ or closed $A$, remember the example cited by @DavideGiraudo with $A$ as a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ of elements of $X$ which converges to $x$ with $x_i\neq x$ for each $i$. Then define $\mu_n$ as the Dirac measure at $x_n$ and $\mu$ at $x$ and $F:=\{x\}$. Hence if you already know that in the general statement
$$\limsup_n\mu(F)\overset{\large{\leqslant}}{\geqslant}\mu(F)$$
for a closed set $F$ then we know that the correct option is $\leqslant$.

Comment: Thanks. What about remembering whether the $\limsup$ goes with open or closed?